# Capistrano destination path already exists, not an empty directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

While deploying a Rails app with Capistrano on Ubuntu 14.04, I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: destination path '/var/www/APP-NAME/repo' already exists and is not an empty directory.


cf5a389e] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/rd/repo/HEAD ] on LINODE-INSTANCE-IP
DEBUG[cf5a389e] Command: [ -f /var/www/rd/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG[cf5a389e] Finished in 0.005 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG[8899b95c] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/rd; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/rd'" 1>&2; false; fi on LINODE-INSTANCE-IP
DEBUG[8899b95c] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/rd; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/rd'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[8899b95c] Finished in 0.005 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO[fc5f524b] Running /usr/bin/env git clone --mirror GIT_REPO_URL /var/www/APP-NAME/repo on LINODE-INSTANCE-IP
DEBUG[fc5f524b] Command: cd /var/www/APP-NAME && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/rd/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git clone --mirror GIT-REPO-URL /var/www/APP-NAME/repo )
DEBUG[fc5f524b] fatal: destination path '/var/www/APP-NAME/repo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Here are config files:

- [config/deploy/production.rb](http://pastebin.com/r0kwHpTG)
- [config/deploy.rb](http://pastebin.com/fmmJkZBv)

The [only reason](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/zOpCpwgFKpY) for this error I can find online is;

> same host in more than one role, so that they're racing? For example I mean that you might have the same IP address defined as an :app role host more than once.

Which I guess isn't fitting with the above config files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. The reason is in double definition of the role and/or server.
Try to remove

```
server 'SERVER-IP', user: 'USERNAME', roles: %w{app}
```

in production.rb and

```
role :app, "SERVER-IP"
```

in deploy.rb. The latter seems to be just simple syntax while the former - is extended one, so you in fact you declare roles twice (three time to be more precise: 2 in production.rb and 1 in deploy.rb). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @leger. I removed the above 2 lines but still the error persists on deploy. Though I think I am on the right track now, had been stuck on it for the last 3hours.

Comment: Try to delete APP-NAME on the server via `rm -rf` and redeploy. I've ran all my iterations in this way, until deployment end up successfully. Sometimes with `sudo reboot` :)

Comment: This did it for me. Was changing a deploy from svn to git. Simply needed to delete the existing 'repo' directory (the old svn repo cache). All good after that. :)

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, I ran into this issue when changing my DB connections file setup on one of my deploys.

In this case, the old structure had one shared file for DB settings, while the newer had two. Even though these were declared in the recipe, I was getting errors when automated deletion of older builds were being done.

To resolve, I just deleted the older builds, and ran the `cap [server name] deploy` a few times to clear it out, and to verify this was no longer occurring. So far, it's been fine.