# capistrano 3 deploy errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, capistrano3

I use capistrano 4.4, nginx, unicorn. when I deploy, I have such errors:

bin/cap production deploy:check works fine.

when I run bin/cap production deploy for the first time, I have an error:

```
...
 [7e794b92]     Cloning into bare repository   
'opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo'...
INFO [7e794b92] Finished in 3.847 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [19e30ae6] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist 'opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deployuser@128.199.226.61
DEBUG [19e30ae6] Command: if test ! -d opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist 'opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [19e30ae6]    Directory does not exist 'opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo'
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
....
```

When I run it again, it says:

```
[4daafe62] Command: cd opt/www/foreignernetwork && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/foreignernetwork/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git clone --mirror https://github.com/KonstantinSmirnov/foreignernetwork.git opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo )
DEBUG [4daafe62]    fatal: destination path 'opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
....
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: destination path 'opt/www/foreignernetwork/repo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
....
```

If I delete this folder, it repeates again the same.

Here are my files:

deploy.rb:

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'foreignernetwork'
set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/KonstantinSmirnov/foreignernetwork.git'
set :scm, 'git'
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :deploy_to, 'opt/www/foreignernetwork'
set :user, 'deployuser'
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets}
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true, :port => 12531 }
set :use_sudo, true

namespace :deploy do

%w[start stop restart].each do |command|
desc 'Manage Unicorn'
task command do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
    execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)} #{command}"
  end
end
end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
  # Here we can anything such as:
  # within release_path do
  #  execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
  # end
    end
  end

end
```

production.rb:

```
role :app, %w{deployuser@128.199.226.61}
role :web, %w{deployuser@128.199.226.61}
role :db, %w{deployuser@128.199.226.61}
```

unicorn.rb:

```
root = "/opt/www/foreignernetwork/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.foreignernetwork.sock"
worker_processes 1
timeout 30
```

please could you help me to figure out how to fix it? Already digged out everything...

Comment: Could you check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314972/capistrano-destination-path-already-exists-not-an-empty-directory) post answers your question?

Comment: no, I already checked, I have no doubling..

Comment: will try to do all stuff from the beginning

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing

```
role :app, %w{deployuser@128.199.226.61}
role :web, %w{deployuser@128.199.226.61}
role :db, %w{deployuser@128.199.226.61}
```

with

```
server '128.199.226.61', roles: %w(app web db), primary: true, user: 'deployuser'
```

in your production.rb

As far as I've read, capistrano is running into race conditions trying to perform identical tasks under different roles when you write three separate clauses pertaining to one IP.